# Is possible in kotlin to assign delegate to property in init block?

Tags: kotlin

Properties in kotlin can be initialized in init block:

```
val a: String
init {
    a = "aaa"
}
```

Can I initialize property by delegate in init block?

Answer (score 2):

Property delegation can only be done where the properties (or local variables, since [1.1](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew11.html#local-delegated-properties)) are declared, you can't do it later in an `init` block. You can see this being defined in the Kotlin grammar [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#property):

```
property
  : modifiers ("val" | "var")
      typeParameters?
      (type ".")?
      (multipleVariableDeclarations | variableDeclarationEntry)
      typeConstraints
      ("by" | "=" expression SEMI?)?
      (getter? setter? | setter? getter?) SEMI?
  ;
```

There is no use explaining this entire part of the grammar, but you can quickly see that it describes property declarations, which always contains a `val` or a `val` at the beginning, and then there's the `by` of delegation somewhere afterward, followed by an `expression` describing the delegate.

There is only one other appearance of the `by` keyword in the grammar, which of course is when it's used for class delegation.

Answer (score 1):

You can just delegate to another property.

```
class Foo {
    private val del: ReadWriteProperty<Foo, String> 
    init { del = Delegates.notNull() }
    val bar by del
}
```